# Report Builder Drill Through Fails

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have been creating reports that include drillthrough. It was successful, everything worked but then the next day it gives me an error...For example, a certain parameter is missing...but I did not make any changes after the report was successfully ran the previous day..Same thing happened to multiple reports at different times. It is quite frustrating because I even made screenshots that everything worked at first but the next day everything failed...Such a mystery...

If anyone has any ideas about it, it would be highly appreciated...

Thank you.

Comment: so what have you done to trouble shoot? have you tried to printout the parameters on the main report? is it in the same format that is expected on the sub report?.. can you show some screen shots.. whats the error message?

Comment: Maybe there was a change to the parameters in the drill through proc. Seems to be the only thing that would cause this error other than someone purposefully doing it.